# Modulus Operation Returning Weird Results

Tags: java

This program divides a number and calculates its quotient and remainder. But I'm getting odd results for the modulus operation.

```
public String operater(int arg1, int arg2) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    int quotient;
    int remainder;
    String resString;

    // Check for Divide by 0 Error.
    if(arg2 == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Argument!");
    }
    else
    {
        quotient = arg1 / arg2;
        remainder = arg1 % arg2;
        resString = "Quotient: " + Integer.toString(quotient) + 
            Remainder: " + Integer.toString(remainder);
    }

    return resString;
}
```

58585 / -45 gives the quotient as -1301 and remainder as 40. But Google says that 58585 % -45 = -5. I think the reason that there are special rules to dealing with signs when doing signs.

From [Modulo Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation):

> "However, this still leaves a sign ambiguity if the remainder is
>   nonzero: two possible choices for the remainder occur, one negative
>   and the other positive, and two possible choices for the quotient
>   occur. Usually, in number theory, the positive remainder is always
>   chosen, but programming languages choose depending on the language and
>   the signs of a and/or n.[6] Standard Pascal and ALGOL 68 give a
>   positive remainder (or 0) even for negative divisors, and some
>   programming languages, such as C90, leave it to the implementation
>   when either of n or a is negative. See the table for details. a modulo
>   0 is undefined in most systems, although some do define it as a."

I want to fix my program but, I don't understand what that means.

Comment: If you want to know exactly what the Java `%` operator does then see the Java Language Specification: [15.17.3. Remainder Operator %](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)

Comment: That text is talking about the different ways that different programming languages could implement modulo / remainder operators.  What you need to understand is how Java implements `%`.    Repeat your Google search, but include "java" as one of the search terms.

Comment: Or ... just go straight to your Java textbook / tutorial / lecture notes, and read what *they* say.

Comment: *" But Google says that 58585 % -45 = -5"* - That is not strictly relevant.  What do the requirements for your exercise say that the answer should be?  Do they say that the answer should be the same as what Google says?

Comment: @ Stephen C: I'm learning on my own, so I don't have a textbook/tutorial. I haven't practiced math in a long time. I'm out of touch and I don't understand the reason why I'm getting incorrect results. I gather that this is an arbitrary thing?

Comment: There is no modulus operator in Java. It is a [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), and its correct behaviour is specified by that reference and by nothing else.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know the difference. I just want the remainder but I'm getting arcane rules. I still don't understand why my remainder values are wrong. I'm trying to read that link, but I don't really get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want. In math, and in some programming languages if the modulo is not zero, then it has the same sign as the divisor, treating integer division as truncating towards negative infinity. In other programming languages, if the modulo is not zero, it has the same sign as the dividend, treating integer division as truncating towards zero. Some programming languages include both a modulo operator (sign same as divisor) and remainder operator (sign same as dividend).

With the mathematical type of modulo, then r = (a + k*b)%b returns the same value for r regardless if k is negative, zero, or positive. It also means that there are only b possible values for any dividend modulo b, as opposed to the other case where there are 2*b - 1 possible values for a dividend modulo b, depending on the sign of the dividend.

C example to make modulo work the way it does in mathematics:

```
int modulo(int n, int p)
{
int r = n%p;
    if(((p > 0) && (r < 0)) || ((p < 0) && (r > 0)))
        r += p;
    return r;
}
```